# Kafka consumer listening to two events/topics

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way i can consume two topics and wait for these two events to proceed consumption?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way i can consume two topics?

You can consume multiple topics in Kafka consumer. If you are using `KafkaJS`, then here is the [example](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming) and a snippet is below

```
// Subscribe can be called several times
await consumer.connect()

await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'topic-B' })
await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'topic-C' })

// Alternatively, you can subscribe to multiple topics at once using a RegExp:
await consumer.connect()

await consumer.subscribe({ topic: /topic-(eu|us)-.*/i })
```

Note that the consumer will not match topics created ***after*** the subscription

Answer (score 0):

I use like this

```
await consumer.subscribe({
      topic: /^topic-/,
      fromBeginning: true, // Set to false if you want to start consuming from the latest offset
    });
```

it means subscribe all of topic like this pattern as topic-B, topic-C, topic-etc.
but if you want to fix the topic of subscribing you can follow the answer in the first answer.